# I want to know the difference between cvWaitKey(0) and cvWaitKey(10)

Tags: java, opencv

```
cvShowImage("SMART", cropped);
cvWaitKey(10);

cvShowImage("SMART", cropped);
cvWaitKey(0);
```

What is the difference between these two functions and when i use this in infinite for loop `cvWaitKey(10)` works but `cvWaitKey(0)` or `cvWaitKey(30)` do not work. What is the reason?

Comment: _Do not work_ ... what's the error / problem? [Read the doc!](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#waitkey)

Comment: In the same window I am getting the real time image frames. When i use cvWaitKey(0), I haveto close the window to get the next frame with another window.
but cvWaitKey(10) works.

I want to use a rasberryPi switch to do this. when the switch is pressed i want to stop the program running. I am new to opencv and rasberryPi

Comment: just use `if ((waitKey(1) & 0xFF) == 'q') break;` or something similar. You the window is  always refreshed, and only if you press "q" you stop the program

Comment: how can you access/read the raspberry pi switch programmatically? cv:waitKey only uses keyboard keys.

Comment: Thank you for your ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference can be found in the documentation of OpenCV of the [`waitKey`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#waitkey) function.

Basically, the function `waitKey` waits for a key to be pressed, and the argument is the amount of time it will wait. So, when you use 10. It will wait 10 milliseconds and then continue with the program.

The documentation says:

> 0 is the special value that means “forever”

So, when you use 0. The program will wait for key to be pressed forever... Just pressing any key will continue the program... (also closing the window will do it)

I recommend to use 10 when you are doing a stream of pictures (maybe from a camera). And use 0, when you are expecting human interaction for the program to continue. And a bigger value if you want to see it for enough time, but continue the program without any interaction.

Comment: @Dilz if you like the answer and think that it solves your question, accept it to let other people know.